# Event Listener Update Doesn't Change Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In order to update the update updatedTime property of the parent when the child was changed I decided to use event listeners in Hibernate. I have read many stackoverflows questions and VladMihalcea blogs and thought, that I can do it, however I am stuck.

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventListenerConfig {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
//        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST).prependListener(CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);
//        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE).prependListener(CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);
//        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.DELETE).prependListener(CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_UPDATE).prependListener(CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);
//        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.FLUSH_ENTITY).prependListener(CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

What I observe is when I add my EventListener for PERSIST and DELETE everything works as expected( I see that the time is changed and the change is propagated to the database). However I have a problem with update. I have tried using SAVE_UPDATE, UPDATE, FLUSH_ENTITY from the VladMihalcea blog, however still I am unable to see the change being propagated to the database(i have logs turned on)

This is code from my CustomEventListener. ( the method update chain and get related works correctly as I see the update when I persist or delete child entity)

```
public class CustomEventListener implements PersistEventListener, DeleteEventListener, SaveOrUpdateEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener {
    public static final CustomEventListener INSTANCE = new CustomEventListener();

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        updateRelatedObjects(event.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        updateRelatedObjects(event.getEntity());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        updateRelatedObjects(event.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(DeleteEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        updateRelatedObjects(event.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(DeleteEvent event, Set transientEntities) throws HibernateException {
        onDelete(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event, Map createdAlready) throws HibernateException {
        onPersist(event);
    }

    private void updateRelatedObjects(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof BaseClass) {
            BaseClass rootAware = (BaseClass) object;
            rootAware.getRelated().ifPresent(BaseClass::updateChain);
        }
    }
}
```

Do You know what did I forget about when updating the entity? Have I missed something? If that's how it works, how can I do the update of my relatedObject?